# XML data filtering and searching

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following chunk of XML code that I can easily generate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sessions>
  <session date="14.10.2016" time="0:1" amount="1">
    <Folder>C:\Users</Folder>
    <Folder>C:\Tes2t</Folder>
    <Folder>C:\Asgbsf\Aleksei</Folder>
  </session>
  <session date="14.10.2016" time="15:40" amount="7">
    <Folder>C:\Users</Folder>
    <Folder>C:\Tes2taaaa</Folder>
    <Folder>C:\Asgbsf\Aleksei</Folder>
  </session>
</sessions>
```

I am searching for data with attribute time 15:40 and date 14.10.2016 using following function

```
private static IEnumerable<XElement> FindElements(string filename, string date, string time)
{
    XElement x = XElement.Load(filename);

    return x.Descendants().Where(e => e.Attributes("date").Any(a => a.Value.Equals(date)) &&
    e.Attributes("time").Any(a => a.Value.Equals(time)));
}
```

Function being executed like:

```
foreach (XElement x in FindElements(pathToXml, "14.10.2016", "15:40"))
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

Everything is fine, but the output is

```
<session date="14.10.2016" time="15:40" amount="7">
    <Folder>C:\Users</Folder>
    <Folder>C:\Tes2taaaa</Folder>
    <Folder>C:\Asgbsf\Aleksei</Folder>
</session>
```

And I need just the folders, eg.

```
<Folder>C:\Users</Folder>
<Folder>C:\Tes2taaaa</Folder>
<Folder>C:\Asgbsf\Aleksei</Folder>
```

How do I achieve this? Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently returning the `Element` that has attribute of `date` and `time` with these values. What you should add to it is to return its child elements of `Folder`. You can do this by adding `.Elements("Folder")` after the `.Where`.

However, I think you can write your query a bit nicer:

Look for all the `session`s that the values of those attriute equal to the given input. Then return the `element.Elements("Folder")`.

*I've added the `.SelectMany()` to flatten the inner list of child elements*

```
string date = "14.10.2016";
string time = "15:40";

var result = (from element in XDocument.Load("data.xml").Descendants("session")
              where element.Attribute("date")?.Value == date &&
                    element.Attribute("time")?.Value == time
              select element.Elements("Folder")).SelectMany(item => item).ToList();
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much, also thank you for explaining, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 4):

(It seems that I am a little bit late, but..) in some cases like this using *Xpath* is easier than *Linq* .

```
var folders = XDocument.Load(filename)
           .XPathSelectElements("//session[@dat‌​e='14.10.2016' and @time='15:40']/Folder");
```

Comment: Agree :) didn't think of that